What does "bumped by community bot" mean?
An edit just said, "bumped by community bot." It didn't say where to, or what "bumped" meant. The HELPS page says nothing about "bumping." Nor the reason why a question is bumped.

Questions get bumped onto the front page occasionally if they don't have any answers, or if they don't have any upvoted answers.

Is this automatic by the system or is it initiated by Moderation or by Staff ?

@NigelJ Completely automatic.
